# problems with cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, restful-authentication

i'm using restful-authentication plugin with rails 2.3.8

i've problems with cookies store

i've put a logger instruction in this function for check the cookie:

```
 def send_remember_cookie!
      cookies[:auth_token] = {
        :value   => @current_user.remember_token,
        :expires => @current_user.remember_token_expires_at }  
      logger.error "--------------#{cookies[:auth_token].keys}"   
    end
```

But when i launch the program i receive this error:

```
undefined method `keys' for nil:NilClass
```

why?

How can i set the cookie?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The cookies object is an instance ApplicationController::CookieJar. It's almost like a Hash but the behavior of the [] and []= methods are not symmetric. The setter sets the cookie value for sending to the browser. The getter retrieves the value which comes back form the browser. Hence when you access it in your code having just set the outgoing value the incoming value will be unset. There some more info on this [here](http://www.40withegg.com/2007/1/5/rails-cookies-mangles-the-hash-interface/)

Also did you intentionally mean to say cookie[:auth_token].keys or did you mean cookie.keys?